# Prevent one particular autocorrect in Google Keyboard

Tags: auto-correct, gboard

On Google Keyboard, if the app thinks you've mistyped a word it will autocorrect it.

Is there any way to prevent the autocorrect occurring in some particular circumstance? I don't want to totally disable autocorrection all the time and I don't want to add the word to my dictionary. If I let it autocorrect I can do two backspaces to undo it, but that's tedious; is there a way to prevent the autocorrect from occurring at all?

Comment: You don't want to disable auto-correction and you don't want to add that word to the dictionary.  So how Google keyboard is supposed to know that this particular word is correct?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, adding the word to your dictionary *is* the solution for this problem.

Comment: Sometimes it autocorrects even if the word it's correcting is a recognized word. For example, right now it just changed "waffle" to "raffle".